the question about VSync(vertical synchronization), coordination of double buffering and triple buffering by time
I've just started learning about computer graphics and I don't really understand how time matching with double and triple buffering. I have the following task that I'm trying to solve(not a homework, just for myself):
For convenience, a display is assumed to draw a screen once every 16 ms (i.e., refresh rate = 1000/16 fps). VSync (Vertical) as shown in Figure.
Starting from the point of time A, which is the synchronization time point, frames from F0 to F10 on the GPU are rendered and displayed on the screen. The time it takes to render each frame is given below the frame number. (Note: In this problem, the length of the Vertical Blanking Interval is assumed to be 0.) If the double buffering method is used while turning on the VSync function, describe the frameFi (i = 0,1,2, ··) shown in each display section from D1 to D5. (Note: Certain frames may not be shown at all or may be displayed in more than one display section.)
My question is to which Di(0, 1 etc.) Fi (0, 1, 2 etc) will go exactly when double buffering? and when triple-buffering? and why? I can't match it correctly with the timeline, I'll be grateful for any help
